# Applying builder pattern or similar on a generated class

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder, consistency

I have the following problem:

A framework generates a class from DB table, each table column is class variable(field).
The generated class has more than 30 fields and just one constructor with no parameters.

To create an instance of that class, I have to use 30 times some setters, which is invitation for inconsistencies.

I cannot use directly constructors with parameters or Builder pattern, as I cannot edit the generated class. What's the best way to approach this - Wrapper class, thread safe methods, a classic pattern?

Comment: What framework is this? What made you think a "builder" pattern is going to be better than invoking the setters, according to you? (just to give us a direction for possible answers...)

Comment: The platform is ERP system - Openbravo, it uses hibernate, but there's an additional layer (DAL-data access layer) on top of that. So all interactions are done via the DAL layer.

Comment: you can use reflection to find all setter methods, you already have the fields name so it'll be obj.getClass().getMethod("set" + fieldName,...).

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer any other (lighter) way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem for myself by making a `BeanBuilder` class that uses reflection on the inside. You give it your bean and then call methods like `startBean`, `value` and similar to fill your bean with data, much like building an XML tree.

If you are in love with type safety, you can make a similar class for yourself that works specifically with that bean that you have.

Comment: I also made a reflection based builder util which can (mostly) automagically build any class you give it or lists of any class. You can specify that certain attributes will have specific values or let it make up sensible defaults. Has proved usefull in rapidally building UI layers without a completed data access layer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an external `Builder` class, that initialises all the fields to some default value whenever you create a new Object, and then behaves like a standard `Builder`.

Comment: This is actually called a factory and not a builder. :)

Comment: @KurtDuBois: Well, you could argue that any `Builder` is a kind of `Factory`, but moving the `Builder` to a separate class doesn't change what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Builder pattern. For instance, if you have `Car` object with field `power`,`weight`,`maxSpeed`,`color` then you can use Builder like this:

```
CarBuilder{
private Car car = new Car();

public CarBuilder(int power,int weight){
car.setPower(power);
car.setWeight(weight);
}

public CarBuilder setColor(String color){
car.setColor(color);
return this;
}

public CarBuilder setMaxSpeed(int maxSpeed){
car.setMaxSpeed(maxSpeed);
return this;
}

public Car build(){
return car;
}
}
```

You can set mandatory fields in costructor and additional fields in settters. Also you can perform some checks in `build` method.